# Calculating speed in Windows Phone

Tags: gps, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone 7 app and I want to see how fast the user is going.

Right now, I am storing the last 2 locations (and timestamps) that were recorded. I am finding the distance between the 2 locations by using the method suggested [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). Then I am finding the difference in time (timestamp2 - timestamp1) and calculating the speed using the formula speed = (distance/time).

Am I using the right method or should I use the [GeoCoordinate.Speed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.speed%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why shouldn't you just use the [GeoCoordinate.Speed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.speed%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property!

The [GeoCoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class already gives you the speed and course (heading) of the movement, so why not just use it?

Comment: For some reason ```GeoCoordinate.Speed``` seems to be returning a constant speed